# google place API not worked

Tags: android, google-api

I need one help, I working in google place search using place api. I enabled place api and map api in cosole app. 
 I created the serverkey also

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key={serverkey}&components=country:gr&input=gf&sensor=true
```

I get following response

```
{
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console",
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

reference website:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/

Comment: please on place api in your google console

Answer (score 1):

Goto on that url: http://console.developer.google.com 
Select your project, after that go into APIs and switch on the **PLACES API**.

Comment: yes I am enable the google place api already but still i get the same error

Answer (score 1):

I am not enable the google place web service api, that why the error appear. Now I enabled and working fine now.

Comment: kindly upvote any answers which hava helped you, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

as the error says "this API project is not authorized to access"

what you can do is

1- create a new project in google console

2- choose the restriction according to your need, if not sure choose **[NONE]**

Answer (score 0):

First Go to google developer console.

Then Create a project

Then go to APIs and auth

Then APIs

Then go to the pic as shown and enable the first api (as you need ios or android)[image]